# Share to an automation app/webhook?

Tags: automation, share-menu

I am working on a project, and it all starts with the share menu on Android. I'd like to be able to take the (in this case) URLs that are shared from various apps, and send them directly to a webhook. Basically, I'd like for there to be an option on the share screen, along with Gmail, WhatsApp etc. for 'webhook', that would ping the webhook directly without any further interaction. I'd rather not build my own app for this...

What I've tried:

- IFTTT - doesn't seem to support this, even with the Android app
- Tasker - I already have it but it doesn't seem to do this, I think there's another paid plugin that might do what I want, but I've struggled with config
- IFTTT again, I can get what I want with a roundtrip via email etc., but I'd rather not...

Is what I want possible? Do I need to make my own app?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.rmy.android.http_shortcuts

Android HTTP Request Shortcuts - which achieved exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Most automation apps could probably support such an task, in [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) (free) it would be:

1. Flow beginning block; start of a task
2. Content shared block; await "shared" URL
3. HTTP request block; call the webhook with URL from #2
4. (loop back to #2)